# Symfony 4 Property "createdAt" does not exist in class

Tags: symfony3, symfony4

Никогда не использовал Form в symfony. Решил закрыть этот пробел и столкнулся с проблемой.

Есть сущность Posts

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PostRepository")
 */
class Post
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $body;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $created_at;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBody(): ?string
    {
        return $this->body;
    }

    public function setBody(string $body): self
    {
        $this->body = $body;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSlug(): ?string
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

    public function setSlug(string $slug): self
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->created_at;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $created_at): self
    {
        $this->created_at = $created_at;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Класс простой формы PostType

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Post;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class PostType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class, [
                'label' => ' '
            ])
            ->add('body', TextareaType::class, [
                'label' => ' '
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Post::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Контролер

```
/**
     * @Route("/posts/new", name="new_blog_post")
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Slugify $slugify
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function addPost(Request $request, Slugify $slugify)
    {
        $post = new Post();

        $form = $this->createForm(PostType::class, $post);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $post->setSlug($slugify->slugify($post->getTitle()));
            $post->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($post);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('blog_posts');
        }

        return $this->render('posts/new.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

При выполнение метода addPost выдает ошибку при выполнении строки

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

ValidatorException: Property "createdAt" does not exist in class "App\Entity\Post"

Answer (score 1):

Правильнее

```
auto_mapping: 
    {'App\\': {}}
```

Comment: А чем правильнее? [Вижу](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/31715), что у кого-то и такой вариант отрабатывает, но интересно послушать почему.

Answer (score 0):

Решением оказалось

```
framework:
    validation:
        email_validation_mode: html5

        # Enables validator auto-mapping support.
        # For instance, basic validation constraints will be inferred from Doctrine's metadata.
        #auto_mapping:
        #    App\Entity\: []
```

Вопрос, на сколько оно верное и почему так сработало?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка потому что нет свойства createdAt взамен его есть created_at. 
Заполнения created_at лучше перенести в event. Для этого нужно сделать следующее. 
Добавить аннотация в сущность и один метод.

```
  /**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PostRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Post
{
     /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function setCreatedAtValue()
    {
        $this->created_at = new DateTime();
    }
```